# SQL Server 2012 Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have pivot solution that works fine but SQL server won't let me save it since it contains queries. Here is my original table:

```
ApplicationID    ApplicationName   ContactType   Email
1                  App1              type1       myemail@gmail.com
1                  App1              type2       someemail@yahoo.com
2                  App2              type1       email@email.com
2                  App2              type3       someemail@yahoo.com
3                  App3              type2       me@yahoo.com
```

Desired table:

```
    ApplicationID   ApplicationName   Type1              Type2              Type3
    1                App1          myemail@gmail.com
    1                App1                            someemail@yahoo.com
    2                App2          email@email.com
```

& so on.... but i want dynamic pivoting meaning if there is new contactType added later on it just gets added to the view. Here is the query that I have which I'm unable to save as view:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(contactType) 
                    from ApplicationContact
                    group by contactType
                    order by contactType
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT  ', coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(contactType)+', '''') as '+QUOTENAME(contactType)
                    from ApplicationContact
                    group by contactType
                    order by contactType
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ApplicationID, ApplicationName, ' + @colsNull + ' 
              from 
             (
                select ApplicationID, ApplicationName, contactType, Email flag
                from ApplicationContact
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for contactType in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

My error is: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'
Please help. Thanks

Comment: I'm inclined to use it as a stored procedure if it is not possible with a view. View is preferred though. Query works great as is in a stored procedure

Comment: why you are thinking to use in view ? i think the best way is storeprocedure

Comment: I want to hook SQL server database to other ERP & Reporting system & it works best with a view

Comment: Maybe the people voting down would care to explain?

Comment: I'm not sure about vote downs either

Comment: Yes. U r right. @jpw

Comment: If your data doesn't have to be real-time, you could use a job to execute your query to populate a table that you can use in place of the view.   It can probably be run quite often since it doesn't seem to be that heavy of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, views are single select statements used to join and/or filter data from tables, TVFs, or stored procedures. As a result the user can't declare variables in a view.

I'd suggest placing this script into a SP where you can declare variables and then calling the SP in the view.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, not stored procedures, unless you mean using OPENQUERY or OPENROWSET (in which case you could also say your view can join and/or filter output of a multi-statement query as well).

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the pivoted result, you can use the below queries.

Declare columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + ContactType + ']', '[' + ContactType + ']')
               FROM    
               (
                    SELECT  DISTINCT ContactType 
                    FROM ApplicationContact 
                ) PV 
               ORDER BY ContactType
```

Now you need to apply `ROW_NUMBER` to display `Type 1`, `Type 2` etc in different rows.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = ' 
              SELECT ApplicationID , ApplicationName, ' + @cols + '
              FROM 
             (    
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ApplicationID ORDER BY (SELECT 0))RNO,  
                ApplicationID , ApplicationName, ContactType,   Email
                FROM ApplicationContact
                
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(Email)
                 FOR ContactType IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY ApplicationID;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/280407/pivot-to-multiple-rows-with-same-id) to view result**

Answer (score -2):

As suggested [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/views-and-dynamic-pivot), you can use dynamic SQL in a view with SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(...), but it's not that great of a solution.   I would recommend using a proc as an alternative to a view.

EDIT - Adding my comment above to my answer:

If your data doesn't have to be real-time, you could use a job to execute your query to populate a table that you can use in place of the view. It can probably be run quite often since it doesn't seem to be that heavy of a query.